# C# Skype4Com / Chats in general

Tags: c#, skype4com, ichat

I've been searching for over a week for a explanatory tutorial or documentation of how to work with Skype4Com. I would like to know how to add users to the current call I'm in.

Comment: https://developer.skype.com/accessories ?

Comment: It doesn't work, says they don't accept beta testers anymore